# How to delete generic list in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I'm passing generic list to my repository to do the delete.But it's not working for me.please help me to solve this error.

```
foreach (var item in oOffersQA)
{
    var record = context.OfferImages.SingleOrDefault(x => 
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.OfferDate) == 
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(item.OfferDate)
          && x.GardenMarkName == item.GardenMarkName
          && x.InvoiceNo == item.InvoiceNo
     );
     context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}
return context.SaveChanges() > 0;`
```

Comment: Can you mention what kind of error you have when using `EntityState.Deleted`? Also `return context.SaveChanges() > 0` is not so recommended way to get deleted count.

Comment: I'm getting this error when executing the code "OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Answer (score 1):

make sure your query return record.
i think you got this exception "OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."
because record = null

```
foreach (var item in oOffersQA)
{
    var record = context.OfferImages.FirstOrDefault(x => 
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.OfferDate) == 
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(item.OfferDate)
          && x.GardenMarkName == item.GardenMarkName
          && x.InvoiceNo == item.InvoiceNo
     );
     if(record !=null)
     {
         context.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
     }
}
return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

Comment: it is returning a record.but still getting the same error.